# How to properly parse a contact's birthday from String to DateFormat on Android?

Tags: android, parsing, date-format, android-contacts, simpledateformat

**What I want:**

I'm writing an application where I want to find out which of my contacts has its birthday today.

**What I have so far:**

I can already scan the phone's contact list and get each birthday as a `String`.

**What the problem is:**

There are three different cases when it comes to the birthday's `DateFormat`.

1. Case: I only know day and month **but not** the year. In this case the stored birthday `String` looks like this: `--MM-dd`. I can handle this one by getting the `String`'s length a parse it with a `SimpleDateFormat` I define.
2. Case: I also know the year. In this case in 99% the the stored birthday `String` looks like this: `yyyy-MM-dd`. I can handle this one too.
3. Case: I also know the year **but** the stored birthday `String` looks like this: `dd.MM.yyyy`. This one has the same length like the one above so that I can't distinguish between the two using the length.

**What I want to know:**

Why are the contact's birthdays stored with different `DateFormat`s? Is this depending on the `Locale`? I tested it with German and English (US) `Locale` and the result was the same. I also deleted and added the birthday in the contacts with the different `DateFormat` (from case 3). They get stored as before. :-/ Is there a way to cover all possible `DateFormat`s for stored birthday in an easy and elegant way without creating all kinds of `DateFormat`s and check against them in a loop?

*Thanks in advance,
kaolick*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to answer my own questions but I found the root of evil:

The reason for the `DateFormat` in case 3 is easy to explain although it took me a while to figure it out. It's because I have Skype installed on my device and these two contacts entered their birthday there. But Skype is using another `DateFormat` (the one from case 3). I looked through the log file and found out that the two contacts also have birthday entries like in case 2 in the "normal" contacts app.

Problem solved! :-D

Answer (score 0):

something simple based on the 3rd char in the string once we know it's not case 1

```
private static SimpleDateFormat MMddFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("--MM-dd");
private static SimpleDateFormat ddMMyyyyFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
private static SimpleDateFormat yyyyMMddFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

private Date Format(String dateString) throws ParseException {
    // possible formats, --mm-dd, yyyy-mm-dd, dd-mm-yyyy
    if (dateString == null || dateString.isEmpty())
        return null;
    switch (dateString.length()) {
    case 7:
        return MMddFormat.parse(dateString);
    case 8:
        return (dateString.charAt(2) == '-' ? ddMMyyyyFormat : yyyyMMddFormat).parse(dateString);
    }
    return null;
}
```

if there's other cases you would have to modify this obviously.

Comment: Not a bad idea. But this won't work if there is a birthday in a 4th format like this one: `MM-dd-yyyy`?

Comment: there's no way to check that, how would you know if I said my birthday is 05-06-1992 if you dont know what format when is my birthday? is it may 6th? or is it june 5th?

Comment: then you need to specify that you're trying to figure out how to parse those other formats as well.